# Hide Specific Radio Button Circle

Tags: css, radio-button

Is there a way to hide a specific radio button with CSS?

I have several radio buttons on my site, but I don't want to hide them all, only one specific one.

The follow code is useful but hides them all

```
input[type=radio]
```

I was thinking assign a class to said radio button with

```
display: none;
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show us how you assigned the class ?

Comment: "*Is there a way to hide a specific radio button with CSS?*" - yes. But without your "*[mcve]*" code how are we supposed to help?

Comment: @James Osguthorpe , You can assign the class to radio button and those which you want to hide write display:none; or visibility:hidden; according to your need into that CSS.

Comment: why downvote me twice for asking a simple question which someone kindly answered straight away. I feel this was slightly unfair!!

Thanks Sandeep, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[type=radio][name=your-radio-name] {display:none}`

You can learn CSS selectors. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: worked perfectly. thank you. and thanks for the link, this is very much appreciated